# Styling Video from youtube player not working like styling an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I am embeding a youtube video by using:

```
new YT.Player()
```

I am using this instead of just embedding an iframe because I want other options such as muting and autoplay.

I cannot seem to get this to cover the complete background like I can with a regular iframe. The video created with the YT.Player() gives  me black bars on either side, while the iframe doesn't, even though the css is the same.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fpkg83mj/

Comment: You autoplay the video in callback--remove that and you can see that the cover is the same http://image.prntscr.com/image/e1f4d9dee06a466689ce649c4b4c6dc7.png

Comment: That fixes the preview. But the video still doesn't cover the entire div when playing. I just noticed that the iframe doesn't either.

Comment: YouTube keeps the original ratio of videos. The best example is mobile phones screen casts.